# Why I can't access my web service from the kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, load-balancing, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to execute an application inside a kubernetes cluster.
I used to launch the application with docker-compose without problems, but when I create
my kubernetes deployment files, I am not able to access the service inside the cluster even after exposing them. here is my deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: myapp
  # type: LoadBalancer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: jksun12/vdsaipro
       # command: ["/run.sh"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 3306
   # volumeMounts:
   #     - name: myapp-pv-claim
   #       mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
   #   volumes:
   #   - name: myapp-pv-claim
   #     persistentVolumeClaim:
   #       claimName: myapp-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myapp-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  accesModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

Here is the result of

> kubectl describe service myapp-service

:

```
Name:                     myapp-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=myapp
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.109.12.113
Port:                     port-1  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 port-1  31892/TCP
Endpoints:                172.18.0.5:80,172.18.0.8:80,172.18.0.9:80
Port:                     port-2  3306/TCP
TargetPort:               3306/TCP
NodePort:                 port-2  32393/TCP
Endpoints:                172.18.0.5:3306,172.18.0.8:3306,172.18.0.9:3306
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

And here are the errors that I get when I try to access them:

> curl 172.17.0.2:32393

```
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
```

And here is the next result when I try to access the other port

> curl 172.17.0.2:31892

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 31892: Connection refused
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 31892: Connection refused

I'm running ubuntu server 20.04.1 LTS. The manip is on top of minikube.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: hint: check the ip you're curl-ing to.

Comment: Seems like a typo in the IP you are using to curl

Comment: the bests practice is also to decouple mysql and your front , here you have db and front in the same containers it's not a best practice for kubernetes , just for your informations

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu  how do I solve it please ?

Comment: @MuhammadHasan thanks I've checked

Comment: I tried on the master node IP address with the hello-world example and it work without problem. But when it come to my app problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are accessing the service from inside the cluster use ClusterIP as the IP. So curl should be `10.109.12.113:80` and `10.109.12.113:3306`

In case accessing it from outside the cluster then use `NODEIP` and `NODEPORT`. So curl should be on `<NODEIP>:32393` and `<NODEIP>:31892`

From inside the cluster I would also use POD IPs directly to understand if the issue is at service level or pod level.

You need to make sure that the application is listening on port `80` and port `3306`. Only mentioning `containerPort` as `80` and `3306` does not make the application listen on those ports.

Also make sure that the application code inside the pod is listening on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I just tried that but it still pop out errors. 

"E0824 09:28:12.020581  925234 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8090 -> 80: error forwarding port 80 to pod 18a8388e04c20a68a069321ceae00179389af9b195f185c5398c7f22ad551aa6, uid : exit status 1: 2020/08/24 09:28:12 socat[1259323] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:80, 16): Connection refused
"

Comment: If you used pod IP to curl and got a connection refused that means the container is not listening on those ports on `0.0.0.0`..verify the code of the application

Comment: I verified again and, I changed the port. Now I can access to the apache tomcat server pages, running inside the cluster. But I have a new challenge now, I can't access the url of the app inside the cluster through the cluster's tomcat server:((

Comment: Please ask a different question for that because it's outside the scope of current question